# ListView and TranslateAnimation negative value not refresh element under others

Tags: android, listview, translate-animation

I apply a negative `toXDelta` in my `TranslateAnimation` and this cause a bug when I scroll into the list because ther is an other list on this one a move.

You can see in this screencapture my problem [image]

Ther is my XML for the orange list

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_list_ghm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/panel_ghm"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="30dip"
    android:paddingRight="20dip"
    android:paddingTop="40dip" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_list_ghm"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And I apply the translate on the `LinearLayout`

```
ll_list_ghm.startAnimation(expend(500, true));
private Animation expend(int anim_ms, boolean is_ghm) {
    Animation collapse = new TranslateAnimation(400, -20, 0, 0);
    collapse.setDuration(anim_ms);
    collapse.setFillAfter(true);
    return collapse;
}
```

When `toXDelta` is equal to 0 or a positive int there is no problem.
Anyone have ever had this bug ?

Thanks guy for reading et concerne about ma problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a alternative solution wich is to set negative margin on code.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp_list_ghm = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels / 4, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
lp_list_ghm.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.ll_list_cmd);
lp_list_ghm.setMargins(-20, 0, 0, 0);
ll_list_ghm.setLayoutParams(lp_list_ghm);
```

But if you have some other solution i'm interested :)